# How to set default options for mounted file systems?

Tags: 14.04, mount, udisks

I would like all FAT volumes to be mounted with the option `uni_xlate` enabled.

How can I configure mount or udisks2 to use that option while mounting the volume?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out is is not possible at all, as explained in [another answer in unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209546/how-do-i-change-automatic-mounts-of-removable-vfat-fat32-drives-partitions-to). The reason is that mount options are hardcoded in udisk2 (see `FSMountOptions` in [`udiskslinuxfilesystem.c`](https://github.com/storaged-project/udisks/blob/master/src/udiskslinuxfilesystem.c)).

A [patch](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/devkit-devel/2015-April/001668.html) has been proposed to make mount options user-configurables but it has not been integrated as of April 2016.

Answer (score 1):

You can set mount options when mounting from the command-line by using the `-o` flag and specifying the options separated by commas exactly as you would with the mount command.
To mount `/dev/sdb1` with the `noatime` mount option, use the following command.

```sh
udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1 -o noatime
```

The ability to modify the allowed and default mount options is now available in [udisks2](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/) as of version 2.9.0.
See the documentation [here](http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/mount_options.html) for how to configure default and allowed mount options.
Since 2.9.0 isn't shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 I also wrote up a tutorial on how to install it from source on Ubuntu 18.04 [here](https://www.jwillikers.com/install-udisks2-from-source) for anyone who is interested.